# How to keep a list of channels in user's cookie and pass to Google Analytics?

Tags: google, analytics

How, if possible, can a list of channels be set to a user's cookie and passed as a custom variable in Google Analytics?

For example, a user clicks on a paid ad on 1/1/2018 and the cookie sets channel to '1/1/2018: PPC'. The user then clicks on a facebook post on 1/5/2018 and cookie updates channel to '1/5/2018: Social; 1/1/2018 PPC'. User then searches on Google and clicks on organic link 1/21/2018 and cookie updates to '1/21/2018: SEO; 1/5/2018: Social; 1/1/2018 PPC'. Demandbase does this, but I can't afford them.

Is this possible? How can this be accomplished?

Would love to see an example.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use Google Analytic's "linear" attribution model in the conversion reports:  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518?hl=en  Or possibly "time decay".